I need a delay before clicking
I tried making a program that autoclicks a specific image once it sees it, but it clicks so fast that the mouse doesnt have time to move before it clicks on the wrong spot. Also i want to add a delay before the first click so that the image has time to load fully and my mouse can get to it before it actually clicks. This is my code:
from pyautogui import * 
import pyautogui 
import time 
import keyboard 
import random 
import win32api, win32con 
from cv2 import imread

while 1: 
    try: 
        pyautogui.click((pyautogui.locateOnScreen('trice1.png', confidence=0.8)) 
        time.sleep(0.5) 
    except: 
        pass


My suggestion is:

Locate the .png

Move the mouse pointer there with duration = 0.5 sec

Click it
# Locate the image on the screen
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('trice1.png', confidence=0.8)

if location:
   # Move the mouse to the location with a duration
   pyautogui.moveTo(location, duration=0.5)
   # Click at the location
   pyautogui.click(location)
   # Wait for 0.5 seconds
   time.sleep(0.5)



